# Near Death experience

Tags: death

I have heard this narration from one of my aunt and cousin.

**Narration 1** : My cousin's grandpa was an Acharya and in his old age, he was on bed and his son (my cousin's dad) went near him at night, and asked dad how are you, is your health feeling better now, he asked him has everyone eaten dinner, his son said yes, and grandpa said 'Chalo' as if to someone else, and suddenly he started breathing heavily and within seconds died. So, did the yamdoot waited for him to communicate with this son ?

**Narration 2** : My aunt's father was in his old age ill and bed ridden, so most of the times some or the other family member used to be present near him. One day he was frequently shouting why is this muslim guy staring at me and asking me to come. Others were not able to see anyone, as after few minutes he died.

My question is, do people who are about to die, see yamdoot's, if yes then what is there appearance like ?, does everyone see them like the one who die normally without diseases / accident ?

Comment: Some of the paranormal issues can never be explained by quoting scriptures.  Everyone can quote one or the other incidents, which might be true also, but cannot be explained.